# Merge multiple lists based on List priority

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a few lists, and each list has a different priority.
When I merge these lists I expect to see the "most common" items first (those that appear in *all* lists), followed by less common items *ordered by the priority of the list they came from.*

Here is an example use case of three lists with overlapping content.

```
lStr    lStr2   lStr3

111             111
112     112
113     113     113
114
115
        118
        119     119
                120
```

The Merged list is expected to be like this:

```
113 -- this should come on top as it is common in all 3 
112 -- this should come next as it is common to lStr and lStr2
111 -- this should come next as it is common to lStr and lStr3
114 -- this is not common to any but has priority 1
115 -- this is not common to any but has priority 1
119 -- this is common with lstr3 and lstr2
118 -- this is not common but has priority 2
120 -- this is not common but has priority 3
```

The sample code below matches this use case, building the three input lists.

How do I merge these lists as described, respecting list priority and repetition?

Note: Please keep performance issues in mind, also list size, and number of lists may vary.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListMerge {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<String> lStr = new ArrayList<String>(); // has priority 1
        List<String> lStr2 = new ArrayList<String>(); // has priority 2
        List<String> lStr3 = new ArrayList<String>(); // has priority 3

        // find another use case whith equal priority
        List<String> lStr4 = new ArrayList<String>(); // has priority 2 // has equal priority to lStr2
        List<String> lStr5 = new ArrayList<String>(); // has priority 1 // has equal priority to lStr

        lStr.add("111");
        lStr.add("112");
        lStr.add("113");// common
        lStr.add("114");
        lStr.add("115");

        System.out.println(lStr);

        lStr2.add("112");
        lStr2.add("113"); // common
        lStr2.add("118");
        lStr2.add("119");

        System.out.println(lStr2);      

        lStr3.add("113");// common
        lStr3.add("119");// common to lsr2 
        lStr3.add("111");// common to lsr1
        lStr3.add("120");// new         

        // when the merge happens the result list should like like the following 
        // use case 1 with different priorities 
        // sorted data should look similar to follow
        /*
            113 -- this should come on top as it is common in all 3 
            112 -- this should come next as it is common to lStr and lStr2
            111 -- this should come next as it is common to lStr and lStr3
            114 -- this is not common to any but has priority 1
            115 -- this is not common to any but has priority 1
            119 -- this is common with lstr3 and lstr2
            118 -- this has priority than any lstr2
            120 -- this has the lowest priority
        */


        // use case 2 with some cases with similar priorities 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an upper limit for the number of lists?

Comment: How exactly does an item from a high priority list compare to an item that's found in two low priority lists? Could you just sort the items by the sum of the priorities of the lists they are found in?

Comment: @laune no there is no limit on the lists. This approach is actually writing for a matching algorithm so i was able to get the matches on each item and merging them so that highest matches comes on top

Comment: Is the order inside a particular list relevant?. E.g. if lStr2 and lStr3 are empty, and we only have elements in lStr, does the result preserve the lStr order?

Comment: @tobias_k currently user uses a star rating button for each result (1 to 5)

Comment: @acesargl right if lStr2 and lStr3 are empty there is no need to change the order of lStr..

Comment: @Maddy But if lStr2 and lStr3 are empty, and we only have elements in lStr and the result does not preserve the lStr order, is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the result you expect. It won't handle more than 63 lists at a time. The alogorithm is based on weights that are combinations of the powers of 2, each list being associated with another power of two. Thus, an element from the first list (of n lists) with weight 2^(n-1) outweighs another element that occurs in the n-1 lists n-2,...1, 0.

```
class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {
    private String value;
    private long   weight;
    public Pair( String v, long w ){
        value = v;
        weight = w;
    }
    public void addWeight( long w ){
        weight += w;
    }
    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }
    public long getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }
    public int compareTo(Pair other){
        return this.weight > other.weight ? -1 :
            this.weight == other.weight ? 0 : 1;
    }
}

public static List<String> merge( List<String>... lists ){
    Map<String,Long> v2w = new HashMap<>();
    // combine the lists, adding the weights according to list priorities.
    long w = 1 << lists.length - 1;
    for( List<String> list: lists ){
        for( String s: list ){
            Long weight = v2w.get(s);
            if( weight == null ){
                weight = w;
            } else {
                weight += w;
            }
            v2w.put( s, weight );
        }
        w = w >> 1;
    }
    // create the list of Pair values: String+weight
    List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
    for( Map.Entry<String,Long> vw: v2w.entrySet() ){
        pairs.add( new Pair( vw.getKey(), vw.getValue() ) );
    }
    // sort
    Collections.sort( pairs );
    // extract result list
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for( Pair pair: pairs ){
        res.add( pair.getValue() );
    }
    return res;
}
```

You can call this:

```
List<String> ml = merge( lStr1, lStr2, lStr3 );
for( String s: ml ){
    System.out.println( s );
}
```

Comment: This solution is valid only if the order in a particular list is not relevant. Weight is calculated based on the lists that contains and element, but the position of this element in a particular list is not considered. E.g. the case when we have only 1 list the weight is the same for all elements. Maddy must specify if the order inside a list is relevant or not.

Comment: @acesargl you are 100% correct about the weight, i am not looking to sort the items in the list1 if it is only the list.

Comment: @acesargl I think this is what i was looking at, testing with different scenarios and will accept solution after that

Comment: @Maddy Seeing your comment that the number of lists isn't limited: the Long weight can be replaced by a BigInteger weight without much change in the code, but it'll run slower, depending on the total number of elements (in the sort). But I think that *computing* the ranking in O(n) with one visit of each element in the n lists is preferable to any algorithm where lists are iterated repeatedly, passing through filters.

Comment: @laune Yes i am targeting this algorithm for unlimited(keeping future requirements in mind) but in my case, List size will be 100 max and number of lists will be not more than 20. 100 limitation because of the salesforce query result limitation. Running up to 20 different criteria queries and joining based on the weight to get the best possibility on the top.

Comment: @laune i converted the java code to a equal sales force code :)

Comment: OK, so the Long is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Having a hard time putting this algorithm into words. You maintain a result list, loop over the lists from lowest to highest priority and promote items as you populate the result list if you have already found them in a lower priority list.

```
  public static List<String> priorityMerge(List<String> ... reversePriority) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for( List<String> list : reversePriority){
        List<String> intersection = intersection(result, list);
        result.removeAll(intersection);
        result.addAll(0,difference(list, intersection));
        result.addAll(0,intersection);
    }
    return result;
}

private static List<String> difference(List<String> list, List<String> list2) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.addAll(list);
    result.removeAll(list2);
    return result;
}

private static List<String> intersection(List<String> list, List<String> list2) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.addAll(list);
    result.retainAll(list2);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear how the rules for combining priority are, but I suggest you just try to add up all the priorities the items have in the different lists and sort them by that combined priority.

```
public static <T> List<T> priorize(Map<List<T>, Integer> listsToPriority) {
    Map<T, Integer> totalPriority = new HashMap<T, Integer>();
    List<T> allElements = new ArrayList<>();

    for (List<T> list : listsToPriority.keySet()) {
        int priority = listsToPriority.get(list);
        for (T x : list) {
            if (totalPriority.containsKey(x)) {
                totalPriority.put(x, totalPriority.get(x) + priority);
            } else {
                totalPriority.put(x, priority);
                allElements.add(x);
            }
        }
    }
    // sort by total priority in reverse order
    allElements.sort(new Comparator<T> () {
        public int compare(T x, T y) {
            return totalPriority.get(y).compareTo(totalPriority.get(x));    
        }
    });
    return allElements;
}
```

Usage:

```
Map<List<String>, Integer> priorizedLists = new HashMap<>();
priorizedLists.put(lStr,  3); // 3 == high priority
priorizedLists.put(lStr2, 2);
priorizedLists.put(lStr3, 1); // 1 == low priority
priorizedLists.put(lStr4, 2);
priorizedLists.put(lStr5, 3);

List<String> priorized = priorize(priorizedLists);
System.out.println(priorized);
```

Output:

```
[113, 112, 111, 119, 114, 115, 118, 120]
```

Some notes:

- For this approach, items with *high* priority should actually have a *high* priority number, i.e. what has priority 1 in your example, has priority 3 in mine, but this should be easy to translate.
- The output does not exactly match your output, but as I said, the rules for combining priorities are not 100% clear. You can replace the `+` with `*` to compute the product of all the priorities; this will in fact get the result that you want, but I do not know whether this makes sense in your setting.

Comment: Getting a compilation error for this line is there anything missing where is the Y value defined allElements.sort((x, y) -> totalPriority.get(y).compareTo(totalPriority.get(x)));

Comment: Are you using Java 8? This is a Java 8 Lambda expression. If you are using Java 7, you have to use a Comparator. I've changed this...

Comment: I think there is a major flaw in your proposal to use the product of list priorities for calculating the final rank. Say you have six lists with priorities 6,5,4,3,2,1. Then an element in lists 6 and 2 will have prio 12, and one in 5, 3 and 2 will beat it with prio 30 - which is contrary to OPs intent.

Comment: @laune Well, I guess that depends on how exactly OP wants to combine the priorities, and I do not find that all that clear from the question. You could also use powers of two, but even then an item that has nine 1* ratings might get a higher priority than one with one 3*** rating.